# Generate a CSS file from HTML markup

Tags: html, css, dry, markup, web-standards

I create a lot of html and css pages. Is there a way to markup an html file, than generate a css file from the markup.

Here's what i'm thinking:

**Example Markup**

```
<body id="home">
   <section id="main">
       <article>
           <p>Some content</p>
       </article>
   </section>

   <aside>
       <article>
           <p>Some more content</p>
       </article>
   </aside>
</body>
```

**Example of generated CSS**

```
#home {  }
#home #main {  }
#home #main article {  }
#home #main article p {  }

#home aside {  }
#home aside article {  }
#home aside article p {  }
```

Comment: I would take a look at CSS Lint -- that type of generated CSS would be highly impractical. Never use 2 IDs, and CSS lint actually recommends never using them at all.

Comment: CSS lint is stupid when it comes to recommending not using ids.

Comment: Unless you have another process that strips out any empty css rule, this would leave too much unused css, bloating your css files and making your site slow.

Comment: It would be quite easy to do that, but you'll get a giant CSS that is of no practical use to you. Better analyse the code yourself and add only the styles you need. The result will be better and you'll get there faster.

Comment: @Kerry you could always just check if an inner element has a class name or an ID and if so exclude the parent elements ID or className.
.I like the idea but how are you going to implement it? Are you going to write a program to parse HTML or is it going to be some sort of macro for your IDE or text editor?

Comment: I believe this same question was answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574208/parse-html-file-to-grab-all-id-and-classes-for-a-css-file/4657372#4657372.

Comment: Maybe i'm looking for something that doesn't exist? I just don't see the practicality of writing a boat load of markup, then writing a boat load of css selectors. It seems very redundant. Is there a framework that specializes in this?

Comment: @ James -- I was just responding to the OP -- not my question. Yes, you could but you don't need to write a CSS select for every item that exists. I have written a CSS optimizer per Google's standards and I know how to parse them.

While I don't agree with wholely not using IDs, they are used far too often. Check the optimizations using Google Page Speed or YSlow and read about CSS Optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is: [parse the HTML](http://jsoup.org/) and walk the DOM tree to generate your skeleton CSS file.

PS: that IS very impractical CSS.

Comment: I agree that it's impractical css, but it makes the file very readable and it ends up saving time with future edits.

Comment: @Dan: Less time typing new selectors, more time hunting for the selectors.  Unless your pages are small I'd think the usual way would be faster.

Comment: Hmm... is this the answer of the first-name users?